# Mac - Crontab ruby script that writes to text not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cron

I have followed a few guides and my ruby code manually runs correctly. I remember setting up a cronjob on a ubuntu DO droplet and if I recall correctly I had to restart an environment every time I edited the cron file.

crontab:

```
* * * * * /Users/jackrometty/desktop/rubyTest.rb
```

rubyTest.rb

```
File.open("rap.txt", 'a') { |file| file.write("crontab successful\n") }
```

the command "crontab -l" returns:

```
* * * * * /Users/jackrometty/desktop/rubyTest.rb
```

Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: The file is not executable, is it? And I don't see a shebang in there.

Comment: please provide `ls -l /Users/jackrometty/desktop/rubyTest.rb`?